# Put your hands "in" or "into" your pockets?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct, and why?

- "Put your hands **in** your pockets."
- "Put your hands **into** your pockets."

Comment: Are these sentences intended to be, for example, instructions to a child on a cold day, or requests made by a master of ceremonies at a fundraiser? Would it make any difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of into vs in vs inside](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18366/usage-of-into-vs-in-vs-inside)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per [this Cambridge Dictionaries page](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/in-into),

> We use in to talk about where something is in relation to a larger
>   area around it:
>
> > A: Where’s Jane?
> >     B: She’s **in** the garden.
> >
> > I’ve left my keys **in** the car.
>
> We use into to talk about the movement of something, usually with a
>   verb that expresses movement (e.g. go, come). It shows where something
>   is or was going:
>
> > A: Where’s Jane?
> >     B: She’s gone **into** the house.
> >
> > Helen came **into** the room.
>
> Compare:
>
> > She’s gone for a walk **in** the garden. (She is in the garden walking.)
> >     She walked **into** the garden. (She entered the garden.)
>
> With some verbs (e.g. **put**, fall, jump, dive) we can use either in or
>   into with no difference in meaning:
>
> > Can you put the milk **in/into** the fridge? Her keys fell **in/into** the
> >     canal.

However, even with a verb like put, some additional context can favor the use of one preposition over the other:

- I put my hands **in/into** my pockets to keep them warm.
- Slowly, he put his hand **into** his pocket and snuck out a folding knife.

In the second example, we're placing emphasis on the movement of the hand, so **into** appears to be more appropriate than just **in**.

Comment: I think this is the better answer.

Comment: Yes, the "in your pockets" stresses the end result.  The hands end up in your pocket.  The "into your pocket" stress the action itself of the hands going into the pocket.

Comment: @chadbag - That's true, but "in your pocket(s)" is still very common, even with the verb _put_. [Interesting Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+your+hands+in%2Cput+your+hands+into&year_start=1950&year_end=1990&corpus=15&smoothing=3). (Not an argument from me, just trying to help provide a complete picture.)

Comment: "I put my hands *into* my pockets to keep them warm. -- Slowly, he put his hand *in* his pocket and snuck out a folding knife." I think it is more of an element of style/personality rather than intended nuanced meaning.

Comment: @chadbag but you can't say "her hands were warm into her pockets."

Comment: Anecdotally, "put your hands into your pockets" sounds odd to me. Googling "into your pockets" and "hands into your pockets" brings up this page as the first result, which seems to back this up somewhat.

Comment: @phoog  There is no action to be stressed, so no, that does not make sense.

Comment: @KyleS - I searched for `put your hands in your pockets` and `put your hands into your pockets` on Google books. Both queries returned roughly the same number of hits and provided several dozen examples. I think the "_into_ stresses the motion" argument may be true, but the nuance is so slight that more people don't really think much about it one way or the other until asked to analyze a question like this one. Compare: _Never put your hands **into** your pockets, and jingling of keys and coins is a great distraction._ vs. _Do not put your hands **in** your pockets, keep them free to gesture._

Comment: @J.R. But your ngram shows that "in" is consistently more common than "into".

Comment: @KyleStrand - Ngrams are tricky in that they only allow a string of five words max, and "put your hands in(to) your pockets" is a six-word string. So the Ngram I originally showed says nothing about pockets – those hands could be being put in the sink, in your lap, in your mittens, in the air, etc.

Comment: The is similar to *The dog jumped on/onto the bed*. There is a different preposition used, but the usage of *onto* does not necessarily single out the motion of the dog  any more or less than *on* does not (although, of course, *on* the bed can also mean where the jumping occurred rather than where it ended).

Comment: Compare *He walked in the house at 6pm and asked where dinner was*. By context, *in* is 'equivalent to' *into* here and tells us no less than *into* would, as far as motion is concerned,  at least to this native speaker of American English.

Answer (score 16):

> *Which of these sentences is correct?*
>
> > "Put your hands in your pockets."
> >     "Put your hands into your pockets."

Answer: **Both** sentences are acceptable and correct.

> *Why?*

Because prepositions are flexible words with multiple meanings. Also, there are many cases where more than one preposition will work just fine.

[Check out the Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hand+into+his+pocket%2Chand+in+his+pocket%2Chand+in+her+pocket%2Chand+into+her+pocket&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5). You'll see that both phrases are in use.

Here's another example:

- He pulled a coin **from** his pocket.
- He pulled a coin **out of** his pocket.

Both are acceptable, both mean the same thing, and [both are in use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coin%20from%20his%20pocket%2C%20coin%20out%20of%20his%20pocket&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5).

Comment: +1, but not the slightest nuance of meaning between the two? _I put my hands in my pockets to keep them warm._ -- _Slowly, he put his hand into his pocket and snuck out a folding knife._

Comment: @Fard - You should flesh that out into an answer, and explain how some additional context might make one preposition more appropriate than the other. (My answer is mostly points out that, without that additional context, either one could be regarded as correct.)

Comment: @Fard Did you seriously sneak a snuck into that sentence?

Comment: J.R. I proposed an edit to the other existing answer instead. @Gandalf Why? You prefer sneaked?

Comment: @Fard A lot of teachers consider it to be non-standard at this point in time. There's a lot of disagreement about the usage.

Comment: @Gandalf Well, I went by [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/snuck) and [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snuck). I guess it can pass as _informal American_, at least.

Comment: @Gandalf and Fard. I speak American English and didn't flinch the use of *snuck*. To me *sneaked* sounds weird.

Answer (score 1):

He jumped into the river.
He jumped in the river.
The first one is correct because the stress is on the movement and on the change of position from outside to inside, as we cannot say that he is swimming into the river, we will use ' in' instead. So the sentence " He put hands into his pockets" will be markedly correct.

Answer (score 0):

The word "in" can mean:

- "inside" (unchanging position)
- "into" (changing position from outside to inside)

*Put your hands in your pockets = Put your hands into your pockets*

*Your hands are now in your pockets = Your hands are now inside your pockets*

So both of your sentences are correct and mean the same thing, but using "in" here is more common.