# Walk in/walk into -- meaning difference, and whether there interchangeable in the given context

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

What's the difference between **walk in** and **walk into** in contexts like :

He walked **into/in** my room?

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84098/put-your-hands-in-or-into-your-pockets/84100#84100 this might answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes they are used to mean the same thing, sometimes they aren't. It depends on the context.

"Into" gives the idea of transitioning from outside to inside.

"In" can mean the same, but not necessarily. For example, "He walked in your room" could mean that he was already in the room and he walked (no transition from outside to inside).

But if someone is outside a room and says "I'm walking in your room", they would mean that they're walking *into* the room. Whether that's incorrect or not, I don't know.

Comment: To me, "I'm walking in your room" isn't idiomatic in the sense of entering the room, though I'm sure it would be understood.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between **walk in the garden** and **walk into the room** is:

- to walk into means to enter [a place] or bang into. [walk into a wall] Walk into  is not a phrasal verb. It implies a location or place.
- to walk in a place, like a garden or room means you are already inside the area and walking.
- but watch out for the noun: a walk-in clinic, you don't need a appointment.
- In AE, walks-in is also used for hair dressing salons (no appointment needed).

When used as noun, a walk-in customer is one without an appointment.

Answer (score 0):

He walked into/in my room

Usually, when the verb walk like go and come expresses the movement of someone to the inside of a place, it takes the preposition into, not in.
However, it's correct to use 'in' in the same sense as an adverb, without a following noun of place or space.  For examples:

He walked in and sat down in a chair.

The door was open so I just walked in.