# "integrated in" or "integrated into"

Tags: prepositions, verb-forms

What is the difference between "integrated in" and "integrated into"?

The [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=nctgh-9pyBEC&pg=PA12&dq=%22integrated+in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy19LryojNAhVDv48KHXp-AugQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22integrated%20in%22&f=false) uses the word "integrated in".

> The final category of optical receiver are the ones that are completely ***integrated in*** CMOS.

I feel "integrated into" is correct. Can I change it to the following sentence?

> The final category of optical receiver are the ones that are completely ***integrated into*** CMOS.

Does the meaning change?

Comment: Based on what I find here, I think `in` is correct, because `into` would put emphasis on movement: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84098/put-your-hands-in-or-into-your-pockets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the problem may be the difference in meaning between mainstream English and electronic/computer jargon. The word "integrated" has a special meaning when used in electronics: integrated circuits are electronic chips which combine many functions which (in the past) were discrete units.

English uses "integrated" as a way of describing many parts combined (often as an action) into a whole. Either "integrated" or "integrated into" would be normal in non-computer usage.

Electronic Jargon uses "integrated in" as a way of describing a feature of a device or chip. When addressing a technical audience, either "integrated into CMOS" or "integrated in CMOS" works, but (as Kai mentions in his comment) "into" implies an action (in this case the designing of the CMOS), while "in" is used to specify the features inside the CMOS.

Answer (score 2):

> **integrate, integrate into, integrate with**
>   When the verb integrate is used without a preposition, the intended meaning is generally to add new members, often of a racial or ethnic minority group, to an institution or society.
>
> > *In the 1960s, the American civil rights movement endeavoured to integrate all schools in the United States*.
>
> While integrate with and into are interchangeable, integrate with normally suggests that two groups are brought together.
>
> > *Ottawa’s proposed light rail system must be fully integrated with the existing Transitway*.
>
> Integrate into indicates that a unit is becoming part of a larger entity.
>
> > *Our school policy is to integrate the ESL students into regular classes as quickly as possible*.
>
> <sup>([TERMIUM Plus®](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=9H9T48PxpxSg.html))</sup>

In your sentence, the meaning will change if you change *in* to *into*.

The version with *in* means that receivers were integrated in the CMOS environment.

The version with *into* would mean that the receivers became part of the CMOS environment.